# How can I make a window invisible to mouse events in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent

I created this class, and it works perfectly for make my WPF application transparent to mouse events.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Win32

{
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    public static void makeTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        // Change the extended window style to include WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);    
    }

    public static void makeNormal(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
      //how back to normal what is the code ?

    }

}
```

I run this to make my application ignore mouse events, but after execute the code, I want the application to return to normal and handle mouse events again. How can do that?

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
Win32.makeTransparent(hwnd);
```

What is the code to make the application back to normal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code in your existing class gets the existing window styles (`GetWindowLong`), and adds the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` style flag to those existing window styles:

```
// Change the extended window style to include WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

**When you want to change it back to the normal behavior, you need to *remove* the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag that you added from the window styles.** You do this by performing a bitwise AND NOT operation (in contrast to the OR operation you performed to *add* the flag). There's absolutely no need to *remember* the previously retrieved extended style, as suggested by [deltreme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647345/how-can-i-make-a-window-invisible-to-mouse-events-in-wpf/4647377#4647377), since all you want to do is clear the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag.

The code would look something like this:

```
public static void makeNormal(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    //Remove the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag from the extended window style
    int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle & ~WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for all replys and for this but......

 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'

Comment: @Larsen187: Sorry, my mistake. I've updated the code. It should work now. You need a `~`, rather than a `!`—those are much too close to one another on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This code fetches the current window style:

```
int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
```

This code sets the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag on the `extendedStyle`:

```
Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

All you need to do is remember what `extendedStyle` you got from `GetWindowLong()`, and call `SetWindowLong()` again with that original value.

Comment: No reason to remember the `extendedStyle`. You can just retrieve the current value and remove the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag from it. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647345/how-can-i-make-a-window-invisible-to-mouse-events-in-wpf/4647540#4647540) for more detail.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Agreed, that's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this instead? (this equals window)

```
this.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Comment: I am not sure by what you mean not work. If you have a button on the form you cannot click on it. Set it to true and mouse events start working again.

Comment: I think what he means is that mouse events that occur on the form (such as a click) are passed down to whatever is underneath it in the Z order. He doesn't just want to disable clicks, he wants to make the window "transparent" to these events as if it wasn't there.