# How to disable hittesting on a WPF window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, hittest

I know it is possible - somehow through `SetWindowLong` API or managed property of WPF's `Window` class at the moment of window's creation... but how to do that exactly I do not know. I simply cannot find the information of how to set style of a window so it could NOT receive any system messages about mouse click on it and any click would go **through** the window to the underlying windows.

Does anyone know that style code or something?

Comment: Why don't disable window?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal you mean, setting `IsEnabled` to false will do the trick?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I tried. The window still consumes mouse click events. I need the event to pass to the underlying windows.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647345/how-can-i-make-a-window-invisible-to-mouse-events-in-wpf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag for the window's extended style. It makes the window transparent to mouse clicks.

```
public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
WinAPI.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

WS_EX_TRANSPARENT not enough.

Need `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST;`

And

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 150, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Comment: It seems it **is** enough. (Win 8.1).